# Раскрывающийся список Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, подскажите пж есть модуль AJAX Quick Checkout FREE под opencart (интерфейс по строен на Bootstrap) Способ доставки выбирается радиокнопками хочу переделать в  [раскрывающийся список](http://htmlbook.ru/example/)

```
<select>
   <option>Способ доставки</option>
   <option>Курьером</option>
</select>
```

Как в Bootstrap переделать?

Comment: выход тут только один: ковырять модуль, переделывать кода вывод нужной информации в этом модуле